# Update State so that record is deleted

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state, react-state-management

What is the most efficient way to update the state here so that deleted records are gone without needing to reload page? Can I do state manipulation inside my deleteTime function? Or is a new function required so that it changes state on button click?

```
    const [time, setTime] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('/api/time').then(res => {
            const time = res.data;
            setTime(time);
        })
        return () => {
            //
        };
    }, []);



    const deleteTime = async (id) => {
          await Axios.delete('/api/time/'+id)
        }



<button onClick={()=> {console.log(time);deleteTime(time._id);}} className="single">DELETE</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either delete the specific entry from the `time` array (by setting a new state without it) or re-fetch and populate `time` from `/api/time`. It's up to you which approach you feel works best for your application.

The former would look something like this

```js
const deleteTime = async id => {
  await Axios.delete(`/api/time/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`)
  setTime(time => time.filter(({ _id }) => _id !== id))
}
```

The latter, like this

```js
const fetchTime = async () => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get("/api/time")
  setTime(data)
}

const deleteTime = async id => {
  await Axios.delete(`/api/time/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`)
  fetchTime()
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchTime()
}, [])
```

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the explanation